# Add statements to existing StoredProcedure in mssql2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

what is the best way to alter a stored procedure from C#(2010) Application code itself at installation time of an add-on.

That means there are existing SP's and different add-on's... So that I have to check the SP. is there a easy way of doing this? or do I have to read this with sp_helptext sp.... add or Change My sentence with reader/writer/string... and execute this?

Regards Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I try to run a different way... but I do have some issues.

```
Server srv = new Server(@"server\instance");
        ServerConnection conContext = new ServerConnection();
        conContext = srv.ConnectionContext;
        conContext.LoginSecure = false;
        conContext.Login = "user";
        conContext.Password = "passw";
        Server srv2 = new Server(conContext);

        Database db;
        db = srv2.Databases["mydb"];

        StoredProcedure sp = db.StoredProcedures["spMySP"];
        sp.TextMode = false;
        sp.AnsiNullsStatus = true;
        sp.QuotedIdentifierStatus = true;


        sp.TextBody = SPBody;
        try
        {
            sp.Alter();
        }

        catch (SqlServerManagementException ex)
        { 


        }
```

The String has something like 6000 characters and I only want to change the Body text not the keys itself. The solution postet in the first answer won't work according to the things that I have to many exeptions..   to Declaration etc...

Here I don't want to update the header of the SP, just right after as Begin... but from where I have to use the Body? without the last End?

```
         ALTER proc [dbo].[spMySP]

        @Object nvarchar(20),               -- comments
        @Type nchar(1),         -- comments
        @num_of_cols_in_key int,
        @listCols nvarchar(255),
        @ListColdel nvarchar(255)

        AS

        begin

        -- Return values
```

.... (some Values here)...
        ---#mybegin#---
        ....
        ---#myend#---
        the rest
    end

I don't know from where I have to pick this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in two ways.

1. Run the attached query in "Reports to File" option selected in SSMS  or press ctrl+Shift+F. In the output, replace an existing column (I assume a column exists in all the Procedures and you wanted to add a new column to the Procedure) with "that column name" + "new column name". For example, if you wanted to add "coly" to the existing procedure and "colx" exists in all the procedure then do "Find and Replace" "colx" with "colx, coly". You need to make sure "colx" is not used anywhere in the condition. You should pick the column which exists only in the select clause.
2. Pass those two values as parameters to this script and the script does the job and produces the output.

```
    DECLARE @to_Be_Replaced_Value nvarchar(130) = ''
    DECLARE @replacing_Value nvarchar(130) = ''

    SELECT REPLACE(M.DEFINITION,@to_Be_Replaced_Value,@replacing_Value) DEFINITION
    FROM SYS.sql_modules M
    INNER JOIN SYS.objects O ON M.object_id = O.object_id 
    WHERE O.type = 'P'
```

This may not work for you if my assumption is not met.

Comment: Hi, Okay, some thing is not useful to me. In this case I have to know the exact words to replace. I would like to handle this between a Start String and End string. I wrote some thing like ---#Begin1234#--- and ---End1234#--- to make this union to my code... other add ons wrote similar things to it to get an identifier... And I don't know if a admin would change the SP. And according to Updates I have to finde the begin and end and replace the characters between...... One way is to read the Statement and fill the to_be_replaced Value. are there any other functions to get this value?

Comment: Hi again. I try to replace the Values by using your Idea. The Problem it self is, that I have within the Text that I replace a lot of things like '22' or some other strings... That means I have to wrap everything...??

Comment: Yes, you have to wrap [] around it.

Answer (score 0):

OK it's done.

I used the sp.bodytext for scratching... find my part that has to be updated and store this back to sp.bodytext... starting from begin up to the last end and this will work as expected.

thanks for help